# How can I change the rotation center of a rectangle when drawing it as a sprite?

Tags: c#, xna, rotation, spritebatch, drawrectangle

I am drawing a line in XNA by using a paint picture of one pixel, then fitting that pixel into a rectangle of height 100, with 2, so it appears as a line. This way I can later draw a rectangle.

I also want to rotate the rectangle but the rotation center is always it's upper left corner. How can I change this?

Comment: Do you mean to say that you're creating a new Texture2D that you're later drawing? I don't understand what "fitting that pixel into a rectangle" means. What does your current Draw() call look like?

Answer (score 2):

Use [this overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff433989.aspx) of the `Draw` method. You'll probably want to set the `origin` parameter to a non-zero vector.

Answer (score 0):

Set the Origin parameter in the Draw() method.

```
public void Draw (
     Texture2D texture,
     Vector2 position,
     Nullable<Rectangle> sourceRectangle,
     Color color,
     float rotation,
     Vector2 origin,
     Vector2 scale,
     SpriteEffects effects,
     float layerDepth
```

)

Where:

*origin*

***The sprite origin; the default is (0,0) which represents the upper-left corner.***